# 'performSegueWithIdentifier' is not working

Tags: iphone, xcode4.3, uistoryboardsegue

I have created a `segue` in storyboard named `"CreateGame"`.And called it with my `viewController` to Load `CreateGameViewController` using `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CreateGame" sender:nil]` but is is not working.
it was working some time ago but suddenly it is not working.

I have taken a look of my code. My

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"Segue");
```

}
is being executed each time when i call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CreateGame" sender:nil]` and then `CreateGameViewController's "viewDidLoad"` is being executed (conformed by using `NSLog();` statement) . but `CreateGameViewController`  not showing on screen of iphone.

i am using `NavigationController` So type of `segue is 'Push'`. some times `segue` works or sometimes not. 
Please help me out.

Comment: What's the value of `self.view` in CreateGameViewController's `viewDidLoad:`?  Also, does its `viewDidAppear:` get called?  Any warnings if you run the Product->Analyze menu option?

Comment: No its viewDidAppear: is not getting called. But Why??what can i do for this

Comment: What's the value of self.view in CreateGameViewController's viewDidLoad:? Any warnings if you run the Product->Analyze menu option?

Comment: There was some coding error in my code.I have fixed it.But thank you for the help sir :).

Comment: I am currently having this exact same problem, or so it seems. Could you elaborate on what the problem was? Thanks!

Comment: @Phil ,  A for loop getting called infinite times in viewdidload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a strong feeling that you are doing something in your `CreateGameViewController's "viewDidLoad"`  (may be some looping or some recursion function calling without end) . That would have prevent the screen appears. it would be more helpful if you can provide the code of  `CreateGameViewController's "viewDidLoad"`